# adding image to http request as request body

Tags: react-native, axios, httprequest, multipartform-data, azure-cognitive-services

We are a college team trying to create a food waste reducing app using React Native, and our goal is to use the Analyze Image API from Azure.

AnalyzeImage API takes local image as request body and give back json response.
My team is trying to send the HTTP request to analyze an image using the Analyze Image API.
To add image as request body, we are using FormData as the request body with the local image from the device. Some images are able to get the 200 status response, but many of them gives us the error InvalidImageSize, even if the image is less than 4 mb(They give us this error even if the imageSize is only 120KB. We are not sure why this would happen, but our guess is that while making the FormData for the HTTP request, it makes whole request size too large?

Is there any way to add image as request body instead of FormData to upload local image from the device or simulator? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

In our code, our app takes the picutre from camera and uses uri for specifying the path.

```
const apiPath = `${endpoint}/vision/v2.0/analyze`;

        const fd = new FormData();

       //ImagePicker from other handler will return uri and name for below.
        var items = {
            uri: image.uri,
            name: image.name,
            type: "image/jpeg",
        };

        fd.append("file", items);
        axios
            .post(apiPath, fd, {
                params: {
                    language: "en",
                    visualFeatures: "Objects",
                },
                headers: {
                    "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": key,
                    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
                },
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the quick start sample for analyze local image using computer vision [REST API](https://westcentralus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5adf991815e1060e6355ad44/operations/56f91f2e778daf14a499e1fa). Please follow the [quick-start](https://westcentralus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5adf991815e1060e6355ad44/operations/56f91f2e778daf14a499e1fa) and snapshot of the response.

Analyze local image using REST interface and should be fairly easy to use. The swagger/postman is a good start, you could start by generating a client from there. Or start from the samples and port to other languages.

[image]